How to allow Wireguard with firewalld?
I'm stuck at the most basic step, which is configuring PC2 (10.0.0.3) in order to allow connections from PC1 (10.0.0.1). Just a simple connection, no VPN or anything like that, for now.
I am using Fedora Workstation, and I can't seem to find the rule to make it work. Disabling firewalld works, as well as setting the target to ACCEPT. Both machines are configured to use port 51820/udp, so I'm not really sure what else I should do.
There is a handshake on both sides even when the ping doesn't work, interestingly enough.
So far I have this:
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=wireguard --add-interface=wg0 --permanent && sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=wireguard --add-port=51820/udp --permanent && sudo firewall-cmd --reload
Note: Changing the zone to FedoraWorkstation, the default one, didn't help either.
PC1

[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
PrivateKey = hidden
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = hidden
Endpoint = hidden:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32

PC2

[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.3/32
PrivateKey = hidden
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = hidden
Endpoint = hidden:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32


At a glance, I suspect that you're adding --add-service=wireguard to the wrong zone.
The "outer", tunnel-encapsulated, packets by definition1 do not go through the tunnel interface – what goes through the tunnel interface is the "inner" traffic such as your pings, SSH connections, or whatever; but once the tunnel receives and encapsulates that, the WireGuard UDP packets go through your physical interfaces (eth0, wlan0, and so on), so they need to be allowed through firewalld's standard zones (public, etc), not the zone that has the wg0 interface.
1 If WireGuard packets were to go through wg0, they would be encapsulated again, and again, and again, resulting in an infinite loop.

That is what I thought, but I had already tried that a few days ago, and still nothing. (Ignore the ACCEPT part, it's now set to DROP).
https://imgur.com/AyVYge0

Where are the port numbers for service=wireguard defined? Is it actually allowing port 51820 specifically?

Yes, the template has 51820/udp configured. I used the --add-port=51820/udp option as well, just in case, but the result is the same.

Can you verify what you're receiving or sending in wg0? Do tcpdump -n -i wg0 on both host swhile the other host is pinging your WG address?

Well it seems tcpdump sees the ICMP echo requests. https://imgur.com/l4vRBN3

@hadtrent - If you have an updated configuration edit your question to reflect those changes. Information in a comment is guaranteed to be missed
